# ClassType Conversions - operator + ambiguous

Tags: c++, type-conversion

In the following, I'm expecting `obj` to be converted to an `int` but why does it returns operator + ambiguous in the following?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int X = 0, double Y = 0):x(X), y(Y){}

    operator int() const  { return x; }
    operator double() const  { return y; }

private:
    int x;
    double y;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass obj(10, 20);

    int x = obj + 5; //obj converted to int
}
```

Comment: In general, it is dangerous to provide too many implicit conversions, because the compiler can choose one we didn't expect, or even find several possible convertions. Note that as you have a non-explicit constructor, an int is also implicitly convertible to MyClass, which can cause more surprises in other code. Explicit conversion is safer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because both conversions are equivalent, it's ambiguous.  Remember that the C++ language directly defines `+` for arguments of `double` and `int`, there is no standard conversion involved.

So neither of these functions is better than the other:

- `double operator+ (double, int)` -- requires one user-defined conversion and no standard conversions
- `int operator+ (int, int)` -- requires one user-defined conversion and no standard conversions

You'll need to provide all the usual arithmetic operators yourself, if you want to make this work, and not rely on implicit conversion operators.

- `double operator+ (const MyClass&, int)` -- requires one standard conversion
- `int operator+ (const MyClass&, double)` -- requires no conversions

Now `obj + 5` will have an unambiguous best match.

---

C++0x draft n3245 says, in section `[over.built]`

> - In this subclause, the term *promoted integral type* is used to refer to those integral types which are preserved by integral promotion (including e.g. `int` and `long` but excluding e.g. `char`). Similarly, the term *promoted arithmetic type* refers to floating types plus promoted integral types.
>
> For every pair of promoted arithmetic types L and R, there exist candidate operator functions of the form
>
> ```
> LR operator*(L,  R);
> LR operator/(L,  R);
> LR operator+(L,  R);
> LR operator-(L,  R);
> bool       operator<(L,  R);
> bool       operator>(L,  R);
> bool       operator<=(L,  R);
> bool       operator>=(L,  R);
> bool       operator==(L,  R);
> bool       operator!=(L,  R);
> ```
>
> where `LR` is the result of the usual arithmetic conversions between types `L` and `R`.

Answer (score 1):

You need do an explicit cast to instruct the compiler that you do really want an integer.

```
int x = static_cast<int>(obj) + 5; //obj converted to int
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that defeats the purpose of `operator int()`.  It would look a lot nicer to write `int x = obj.toInt() + 5;`.

Comment: @Ben: I think this helps one to realize the little value of conversion operators... - OP's class is bizarre anyway, if `x + 5` and `x+5.0` have completely different results. Perhaps even go as far as to replace toInt with getX (a descriptive name).

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you could solve this by overloading the `+` `operator` within `MyClass` (as opposed to the global one in [Ben Voigt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366080/classtype-conversions-operator-ambiguous/5366094#5366094)):

```
int operator +(const int rhs) const
{
    return x + rhs;
}

int operator +(const double rhs) const
{
    return y + rhs;
}
```

Tidy and unambiguous.

Comment: Until you want to handle `5 + obj` as well as `obj + 5`.  But the OP is asking for some pretty weird behavior, maybe `5 + obj` isn't expected to do the same thing.